# C++ while switch case make a loop inside default

Tags: c++, while-loop, switch-statement, boolean

I have a problem about using while switch cases ı have a code like this
and I wanted to see if the user wrote other than 1,2,3,4,5, then I wanted to **just print**  "Please enter option" and asked for new input which means I don't want to go back to the choice menu, I know it looks like quite easy and I tried to use a bool and used in inside the while but I got stuck in an infinite loop.

```
   cout << "Welcome to program." << endl;
  while (true) 
    
      cout << "Please make a choice from the following menu: " << endl;
      cout << " Press 1 for this.... ," << endl;
      cout << "Press 2 for this.... . ," << endl;
      cout << "Press 3 for this.... . ," << endl;
      cout << "Press 4 for this.... . ," << endl;
      cout << "Press 5 for this.... ." << endl;
      cout << endl;
      cin >> num;
      cout << endl;
        switch (num)
     {
      case 1: 
        
          cout << "Success!" << endl;
          break;
      case 2 : 
          cout << "You presed 2 " << endl;
          break;

      case 3 : 
          cout << "You pressed 3 " ;
          break;

      case 4: 
          cout << "You pressed 4 " ;
          cout << endl;
          break;
      case 5 : 
           cout << "You pressed 5 " ;
          
         
      default:
             cout << "Please enter a valid option!" << endl; // only print this while user write other than cases
             cin >> num;
           
             cout << endl;
```

Comment: you are never breaking from while loop, so you would be stuck in while loop

Comment: Please use punctuation when asking a question.

Comment: @Abhishek actually orginally when ı press 5 it return -1 and exit from the program but ı can not find a what to make a loop inside default and print enter a valid option while input is not valid.

Comment: Then you have probably put something different in the question description. I tried the code and its running infinitely even when I type in 1-5 options

Comment: completely off topic, but it really bugs me: you are using the character ı which is "LATIN SMALL LETTER DOTLESS I" (unicode C4 B1). Why? What kind of circumstances ended up with you writing this instead of `I`, especially since I see you also use both `i` and `I`. Just curious.

Comment: You don't have selection to quit the program.  Could be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while (true)
```

I can see that you are not using brackets after the while loop, so how are you expecting it to loop properly. It will only execute the immediate next line of code if there are no brackets. So, encapsulate your code inside of the `while(true)`

Apart from that, you are never breaking from the while loop, so you would be stuck in the while loop. You don't have a condition inside the while loop that ever breaks you out of the loop anytime. The `break`s in the switch-case block will only break you out of the switch case block, but you will still remain inside the while loop. So, If you want to break out of the loop, you must break out of the loop outside the switch block.

You could probably maintain a flag which indicates if any of option 1,2,3,4,5 executes, then you can break out of the loop. Or you could think of a logic that suits your use-case. I just pointed out where you were going wrong.

#### Correct Code -

```
cout << "Welcome to program." << endl;
int num=3;
while (true) {
  if(num>=1&&num<=5){
  cout << "Please make a choice from the following menu: " << endl;
  cout << " Press 1 for this.... ," << endl;
  cout << "Press 2 for this.... . ," << endl;
  cout << "Press 3 for this.... . ," << endl;
  cout << "Press 4 for this.... . ," << endl;
  cout << "Press 5 for this.... ." << endl;
  cout << endl;
    }
  cin >> num;
  cout << endl;
    switch (num)
 {
  case 1:         
      cout << "Success!" << endl;
      break;
  case 2 : 
      cout << "You presed 2 " << endl;
      break;

  case 3 : 
      cout << "You pressed 3 " ;
      break;

  case 4: 
      cout << "You pressed 4 " ;
      cout << endl;
      break;
  case 5 : 
       cout << "You pressed 5 " ; 
       break;                  
  default:
         cout << "Please enter a valid option!" << endl; // only print this while user write other than cases
        continue;
     }
}
```

The above code will loop till the user enters an invalid option and break out of the loop only once a correct option has been entered by the user.

Comment: actually ı have brackets but ı could not write in stakcoverflow it is my bad, and ı m not looking for the way to break out from program, but find a way that makes a loop inside the default and if user enter 1 or 2 etc. the program flow will keep goes. ı tried to have a flag in default but it makes infinite loop

Comment: @Razbolt Why do you want to make another loop inside an already present loop. You can continue the loop if the user enters an invalid option by writing `continue;` inside the default statement

Comment: @Razbolt Even if the user enters a valid option in the default loop, you will be looping back from start in the while loop and asking the user input again.

Comment: it is continue to goes inside the while(true) loop which prints out the program menu, however i did not want to print out the program menu while i im inside the default and program is goes on untill the user enter 5 which actually it return -1,

Comment: the continue;  continue to goes inside the while loop but my point is goes again default not the whole program

Comment: @Razbolt What do you want to do in the default? What do you want to happen when user enters any of option 1-5 in default loop?

Comment: think of it  im user and i enter -1, which goes to default and print out you entered invalid.and again asked for new input and this time i entered -2, prints again you entered invalid. again just asked for new integer and dont want to go while(true) loop that prints the flow of program that press 1 for this presss 2 for this ect.

Comment: in my example it prints out you entered invalid and goes again in the while loop while(true) and prints the menu

Comment: @Razbolt Check the above code that I updated. It will print out just what you want, without having an extra looping in the default(which is always undesirable). The above code does what you are trying to achieve in a simple way

Comment: Thanks for your effort, your program is basically printing the menu for once then user should print 1or 2 etc.what ı m trying to say, if user enter a valid input which means 1,2,3,4 or 5 the program of the menu will be shown in the console but if users enter invalid which means default, it should asked user to press valid but not printing the menu , but thanks again for your effort i think using flag in code is usefull but i can not figure out where to use it

Comment: @Razbolt Did you try my updated code? It does exactly the thing you are asking...

Comment: Yes i tried in visual studio it did not work like this but in replit it work like you said but i coudnt figure out why

Answer (score 0):

Anything you don't want repeated, don't put in a loop. It's that simple. Present the full menu and first prompt outside the loop. Your default case will print its message **only** if a bad number was entered. I also shrunk the switch because all that extra typing was unnecessary. `[[fallthrough]]` is an excellent tool, but it requires C++17.

If all you want is a valid input, you really shouldn't bother with a `while (true)` infinite loop. Just iterate as long as your input is invalid.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int num = 0;

  std::cout << "Welcome to the program.\n";
  std::cout << "Please make a choice:\n"
            << "1.\n2.\n3.\n4.\n5.\n\n"
            << "Please enter option: ";

  while (num < 1 || num > 5) {
    std::cin >> num;

    switch (num) {
      case 1:
        std::cout << "Success!\n";
        break;
      case 2:
        [[fallthrough]];  // C++17 needed for this, otherwise leave empty
      case 3:
        [[fallthrough]];
      case 4:
        [[fallthrough]];
      case 5:
        std::cout << "You pressed " << num << ".\n";
        break;
      default:
        std::cerr << "Invalid entry!\nPlease enter a **valid** option: ";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: OP wants the program to print the menu every time user enters the correct input. I don't think your program does that

Comment: It doesn't, and I don't think OP wants that.

Comment: the OP only doesn't want the menu to be printed when user has inputted wrong input (In that case, OP wants *Invalid entry!...* to be printed which your program does), but in other cases he just wants the loop to go on printing the menu

Comment: I see that comment, which is much newer than yours. I will leave my code here as-is. My reasons are that the request makes zero sense, and their english is broken enough that I can't tell exactly what they want. Maybe if they had asked the question properly, like outlining some sample inputs and expected outputs versus received outputs, we wouldn't have to guess and read all the comments on the entire page to maybe get an idea of what the desired behavior should be.